# Python beginner - coding with dtale (command order problem)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Due to a university project where I want to work and learn python, I stumbled upon the add-on dtale, which helps me analyzing party manifesto mass data.

Long story short: I added some filters (e.g. I only want to show rows with an edate >= 20140914. When I run the code, the filters don't seem to be applied - could you please help me with that?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://manifestoproject.wzb.eu/down/data/2020b/datasets/MPDataset_MPDS2020b.csv')
d = dtale.show(df)

# DISCLAIMER: 'df' refers to the data you passed in when calling 'dtale.show'

import pandas as pd

if isinstance(df, (pd.DatetimeIndex, pd.MultiIndex)):
    df = df.to_frame(index=False)

# remove any pre-existing indices for ease of use in the D-Tale code, but this is not required
df = df.reset_index().drop('index', axis=1, errors='ignore')
df.columns = [str(c) for c in df.columns]  # update columns to strings in case they are numbers

df.loc[:, 'edate'] = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df['edate'], infer_datetime_format=True), name='edate', index=df['edate'].index)
d.open_browser()
```

So basically, my goal is to not always have to start filtering for dates etc, but that all my progress is saved and applied when running the code.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I believe adding a small sample of your data frame will help clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are some other arguments you can pass to `pd.read_csv()` that will probably help you out here:

- `parse_dates`: Give this arguments as a list of columns that pandas
  should convert to dates. This might replace your second to last line.
- `index_col`: This allows you to explicitly set an index, which should help you with not having to convert `.to_frame()`

If these don't get you all the way there, I have two ideas:

1. You can put all this logic inside of it's own function called something like `clean_df` and call that on newly loaded data.
2. You can save your cleaned data in a format other than a `.csv`. One (of many) option is that `DataFrames` [can be saved](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) to something called a `pickle`, which is one way [python objects can be saved to memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). Loading `DataFrames` from a pickle brings them back pretty much exactly how you saved them, no need to do all the cleaning.

Also small note, I don't think you need to `import pandas` twice.

Comment: Changed the pd.read to 'df = pd.read_csv('https://manifestoproject.wzb.eu/down/data/2020b/datasets/MPDataset_MPDS2020b.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='edate')', thanks for that!!  --> However, this does not really solve my problem with filtering for 'edates' between 14/09/2014 and 30/08/2020. I tried 'df = [(df['edate'] >= '14/09/2014') & (df['edate'] < '30/08/2020')]' (Key error) as well as df.loc['14/09/2014':'30/08/2020'] (which worked BUT only shows the exact days and only in VSC via jupyter, not in localhost results)

Comment: **edit: made a mistake, `df.loc['14/09/2014':'30/08/2020']` indeed shows all relevant results but just in Jupyter notebook, so when I open the browser with the .csv-file, the filter is not applied. Thanks for your help @zach